# Django Url filtering

Tags: django, url-routing, django-urls

I have a third party app that I'm including in my app:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'webhook/', include('telegram.urls', namespace='api_webhook')),
]
```

Let's say the telegram app has such url configuration:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<token>[-_:a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$', TelegramView.as_view(), name='api_webhook'),
]
```

Now I want to do it in such a way that the `token` argument will only be my own token. Let's say if I have a token `jbhgfjkljnmbvgcfhjbmnbv` then I want to only accept requests to `<mysite>.com/webhook/jbhgfjkljnmbvgcfhjbmnbv`. How do I do this?
If i just include the telegram app's urls then requests with other will be accepted in my app which will cause problems.

Comment: Though I haven't tested it, I think you can write a custom middleware to check the url and raise a 404 there if you don't want to change anything in views.

Comment: I don't want to raise a 404 because it's possible that I have many apps running in my project, and each app processes requests for a different bot. So I just want to each app to only process requests that are sent to their bots (each bot has its token). To be precise, I don't want to an app to receive a request that is not from it's bot (or token)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is just one view, you can create your own view and call it:

```
from other_app.views import other_view

def is_valid(token):
    """Your token validation logic here."""
    return token == "XYZZY" 

def my_view(request, token):
    if not is_valid(token):
        return  HttpResponseForbidden("Bad token")
    return other_view(token)
```

If you need to check all views in the app, create a small [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/):

```
def is_valid(token):
    return token == "XYZZY"


class CheckTokenMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        if request.resolver_match.namespace == "api_webhook":
            if not is_valid(view_kwargs.get('token')):
                return HttpResponseForbidden("bad token")

        return None
```

Remember to add this to `settings.MIDDLEWARE`!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try that